# Fade in next two elements on click

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, show-hide

I try to show two more div's, each time, a button is clicked. I have two problems.

1. It shows just one more on click (should show two)
2. It doesn't repeat after the first click

I already tried with a loop or repeat, but nothing worked. Where is the mistake?

```js
$(".button").click(function() {
  $(".content").nextAll(':lt(2)').fadeIn("slow");
});
```

```css
.hide { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">Content 1</div>
<div class="content">Content 2</div>
<div class="content hide">Content 3</div>
<div class="content hide">Content 4</div>
<div class="content hide">Content 5</div>
<div class="content hide">Content 6</div>
<div class="content hide">Content 7</div>
<div class="content hide">Content 8</div>
<div class="content hide">Content 9</div>
<div class="content hide">Content 10</div>
<div class="button">SHOW ME 2 MORE</div>
```

Here is my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/x25Ldwaj/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic is almost there, it's just the selector that's incorrect. You need to start from the last visible `.content` element, so you can use `:visible:last`, like this:

```js
$(".button").click(function() {
  $(".content:visible:last").nextAll('.content:lt(2)').fadeIn("slow");
  $(this).toggle($(".content:visible:last").index() != $('.content').length);
});
```

```css
.hide { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">Content 1</div>
<div class="content">Content 2</div>
<div class="content hide">Content 3</div>
<div class="content hide">Content 4</div>
<div class="content hide">Content 5</div>
<div class="content hide">Content 6</div>
<div class="content hide">Content 7</div>
<div class="content hide">Content 8</div>
<div class="content hide">Content 9</div>
<div class="content hide">Content 10</div>
<div class="button">SHOW ME 2 MORE</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. And what must happen, to hide the .button, when no content to show is there anymore? Do you have maybe a solution approach, so I can try?

Comment: Sure, you can check if the last item is visible and show/hide the button as necessary using `toggle()`. I updated the answer for you

Comment: Wow, nice! I understand, what you did and the fiddle is working. But I tried in my site, there it doesn't work. I copy/pasted the code at the end, see: http://tanzstudio-ludwig.de/test2.html - why? :S